# Endpoints allowing Protocols other than TCP or UDP

Tags: azure

Is there a way to have endpoints which allow protocols other than TCP or UPD.  For example Protocol 50 / ESP - the protocol for native IPsec.  I would like to be able to hit the "outside" edge of one of my public ip addresses with this protocol.

Answer (score 1):

At this time only the TCP and UDP protocols are supported for Microsoft Azure virtual networks. You can however create a point to site endpoint using VPN; this requires you to download an agent on your client machines. Check [this page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-networking/) for more information.